# Чем паттерн "revealing module" лучше паттерна "module"?

Tags: javascript, шаблоны-проектирования

В чем преимущество такой записи:

```js
let myMod1 = (function() {
  let counter = 0;

  console.log('myMod1');

  let increaseCounter = function() {
    console.log('increaseCounter');
    counter++;
  };

  let getCounter = function() {
    console.log('getCounter');
    return counter;
  };

  return {
    getCounter: getCounter,
    increaseCounter: increaseCounter
  };
})();
```

над такой:

```js
let myMod2 = (function() {
  let counter = 0;

  console.log('myMod2');

  return {
    increaseCounter: function() {
      console.log('increaseCounter');
      counter++;
    },

    getCounter: function() {
      console.log('getCounter');
      return counter;
    }
  };
})();
```

???

Comment: Ни в чём. Просто вкусовщина. Хотя в первом случае будет удобнее писать, если методы как-то вызывают друг друга.

Comment: а чем эти записи отличаются?

Comment: @Alexey Ten можете маленький пример написать, пожалуйста?

Comment: Структурируемость и читабельность [Эдди Османи](https://frontand.ru/revealing-module-javascript-design-patterns-part-4/)

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk "повторять название основного объекта при вызове публичного метода извне" - что это значит и почему от этого можно расстроиться?

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk   "Ему также не нравилось требование Module Pattern использования объекто-литеральной определения объектов в момент, когда он хотел сделать что-то публичным"  - почему ему это не нравилось??????Хоть какое-то объяснение,пожааааааалуйста.

Comment: "Не нравилось использования объекто-литеральной определения" -  это означает, что ему не нравилось использовать постоянно `this` (что бы вызвать например метод `increaseCounter`  в `getCounter` нужно использовать this). В RM это вещь отпадает.

Comment: Второе, закрытие методов в RMP просто удаляется поле из возвращаемого объекта, в то время как в MP нужно удалить весь метод

Comment: Ну и добавлю. Напишите модуль с 15+функциями, десятком переменных, и вы увидидите разницу. В первом случае код получается читабельнее.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko скажите пожалуйста, а подобные функции как-то ухудшают производительность?Ведь они сами по себе вызываются после объявления...можно ли сказать, что они первый раз срабатывают  "в холостую"(до моего обращения к этой функии)?Я говорю конкретно про мой случай,когда просто нужно инкапсулировать приватные методы.

Comment: Нет, на производительность это никак не влияет. Функции не вызываются после объясвления и не срабатывают "в холостую".

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko как не вызываются?Если написать console.log() внутри этой функции, она выведет в консоль то, что я написал, до любых моих манипуляций с этой функцией.

Comment: @Lyy как вызываются? Какую функцию\функции вы имеете в виду? Посмотрите, я добавил работающие примеры в ваш вопрос. Где эти функции вызываются?